# html directory listing formatting

Tags: html, apache, list, configuration, directory

So, I've been trying to get a web page to display links to videos (over a symbolic link) dynamically (i.e., without hardcoding an `<a></a>` tag for each one) I have, and I think I may have found a solution, albeit a hacky one:

```
<a href="./Video/">Video</a>
```

Ignoring that this is a horrible way to do this, does anyone know how to format the following?:

[image]

I'm guessing there is an apache config file somewhere, but it is extremely hard to search for it as I do not know what it is called when files are just listed in this manner.

i'm basically looking to resize the widths of columns, and maybe even do some pretty-fication.

this is all running on my web/file server and is being accessed form my local machine.

Comment: very simple look at the source code. it probably uses tables. do the same

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:
http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/

This tutorial details how directory listing by Apache can be modified to suit your taste using HTAccess file.

Using Apache **HeaderName** and **ReadmeName** directives and the module "**mod_autoindex.c**" you can add custom markup to your directory listing pages.

Comment: whoa, this is really cool.  Would be even more awesome if you could summarize the general idea directly in your answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: who cares if it gets me what i was looking for?  thankyou adeel.

Comment: @Drake Thanks, but Zach's was a valid concern and the link he provided was rather informative. It is necessary to include a brief summary to make sure users know where they're going and what they'll find when they get there.

Comment: I'd like to know if there's a way the custom HTML header/footer can contain dymanic content, specifically the name of the directory being browsed.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem like a supported option. The custom header/footer don't allow any template markup which would allow replacement by Apache.

Answer (score -1):

For displaying links to A/V and other files, look at my website: https://wrcraig.com/ApacheDirectoryDescriptions.

It goes beyond the default directory description, providing a spreadsheet to assist in creating detailed descriptions and exporting them in FancyIndex/AddDescription format for inclusion in .htaccess.

It also provides a menu driven BASH scripted alternative, using the FancyIndex descriptive data above (automatically adding A/V durations) to recursively populate a custom index.html while retaining the security features of .htaccess.

The site has examples of the input spreadsheet and both the FancyIndex output and the optional BASH scripted output.